# Multiple Handling Exceptions in java

Tags: java, logging, exception

I need to handle a particular exception and rest of all other exception which should gives us the same logging information but the level of logging should be different ( Former should be going to log.warn and the rest of them should be going to log.error)

```
        try {
        }
        catch (someexception e) {
         log.warn("some message")
         -----some code----
        }
        catch(AllotherExceptions e) {
        log.error("same message as above")
        -----same code as above----
        }
```

This  needs to minimalized as the message is the same but need to make the rest of the code as a common code rather than writing it couple of times

Comment: Please elaborate by an example. Even better - show us what you've done so far and explain what you'd like us to help you to improve.

Comment: So you want to handle the separate exceptions differently? Or you want to handle all of them at once? @Emoji

Comment: use a `try{ ...} catch(MyFirstException mfe){} catch(MySecondException mse){}`

Comment: Message is the same but need to send to make the rest of the code as a common code rather than writing it couple of times

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to do so. You can, as shown in previous answers, make successive catch statements like this :

```
try {
    // Code that potentially throws multiple exceptions
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    // Manage this particular exception case
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // Manage remaining exceptions
}
```

This way you'll be able to manage particular cases and define a point where all the exceptions related to the following actions will be managed. By putting this `try` statement early in your process (main loop, heavy service call...), you'll manage many exceptions but you'll not be able to manage specific cases since you won't know which particular actions threw them. By wrapping little specific actions (accessing files, requesting...), you'll be able to make very specific management of these exceptions.

As pointed in the answers, with Java >= 7 this syntax will work :

```
try {
    // Code that potentially throws multiple exceptions
}
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    // Manage these particular exceptions
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // Manage remaining exceptions
}
```

This way is to be used when you need to manage different exceptions the exact same way. It's particularly helpful when a single action would throw different exceptions (ie accessing files) but you only want want to manage a few specific error cases in particular and not worrying about everything that can be thrown.

Comment: Message is the same but need to send to make the rest of the code as a common code rather than writing it couple of times

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand what you're willing to do, but maybe the second way of managing exceptions I put in my answer is the key : just make a catch with every exception you consider as warning and another with every one that is an error

Comment: You can check the modified code in the post. I need the code of the same blocks to be given as single time rather than giving the same code couple of times

Comment: I would check for the exception name and if it's in a list of "warning level" then do what you need to do for this case. So only one general catch, two arrays of exception names (one for errors, one for warnings) and a simple finding to determine what level you're on

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `catch` blocks to accomplish this, and catch `Exception`, the base class for all checked exceptions, last.  For example:

```
try {
    // Your code here.
} catch (SpecificException e) {
    log.warn("Warning!", e);
} catch (AnotherSpecificException e) {
    log.warn("Another warning!", e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error!", e)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add several catch sections and finish with a catch all.

```
try {
 // Some code
}
catch (IOException ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
catch (Exception ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
}
```

Read more here: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
//try something
} catch (SomeTypeException e){
//things
} catch (AnotherException e){
//AnotherThings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example, which is valid in Java SE 7 and later, eliminates the duplicated code:

```
try{

  }
  catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
        logger.log(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

since java 7 you can do a try-Multicatch

```
    try {
        new Foo("").doSomething();
    } catch (Exception1 | Exception2  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```